# Imported package not detected "Target of URI doesn't exist" Flutter

Tags: android, flutter, flutter-dependencies

I am building a habit tracker app in vscode, I have used many packages which I have imported with the **pubspec** assist extension.

Today I wanted to add the **flutter_slidable package** but when I import it in my file it gives below error.

The imported package **'flutter_slidable'** isn't a dependency of the importing package.

I checked my **pubspec** file and everything is correct.

Try adding a dependency for **'flutter_slidable'** in the **'pubspec.yaml'** file got below error.

Target of URI doesn't exist: 'package:flutter_slidableaq/flutter_slidable.dart'.Try creating the file referenced by the URI, or try using a URI for a file that does exist.

[This is my import](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tFiU8.png)

[This is my pubspec file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TJU7u.png)

I tried clearing vscode cache by doing
Ctrl + Shift + P
Clear Editor History.

Comment: Have you tried running "flutter pub get" again?  Was the "aq" in "flutter_slidableaq" a typo?

Comment: Yes that was a typo from the person who edited the question. I also did run flutter pub get as well as flutter clean but it didnt work. What DID work though was reinstalling vscode and restarting my device. Dont know why that happened but it works now.